# Problems with array Statement

Tags: php

hello Friends my problem with Statement two string

```
$i=0;
$arr['LAM'] = preg_replace('/\s+/', 'D', $arr['LAM']); 
print_r($arr);
///Array ( [id] => 123 [LAM] => D )

echo '_'.$arr['LAM'].'_';
///_D_
if($arr['LAM']!='D'){
$i++;
}
echo $i;
//1
```

Why $i==1?

Comment: replace your `print_r($arr);` call with `var_dump($arr);` and take the output from the source code and tell us what you get, [right now we can't reproduce your problem.](http://3v4l.org/D8vTn)

Comment: use `!==`. may by type is different.

Comment: tnx fow answer array(17) { ["id"]=> string(76) "123"    ["LAM"]=> string(40) "D" }

Comment: @asghar 1) This means you have 17 array elements and not 2. 2) `string(40)` means you have some hidden characters in there. Take a look with a hex-editor

Comment: yes have 17 elements  just is secret sorry .I can not show. my problem id with elment  ["LAM"] . why $arr['LAM']!='D' is true

Comment: What does `$arr['LAM']` look like before the `preg_replace` is called? I was able to reproduce a working piece of code, but that is based on `$arr['LAM']` initially being `' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
<?php

$i=0;

$arr = array('id' => 123, 'LAM' => ' ');
$arr['LAM'] = preg_replace('/\s+/', 'D', $arr['LAM']);

print_r($arr);
// Array ( [id] => 123 [LAM] => D )

echo '_'.$arr['LAM'].'_';
// _D_

if($arr['LAM'] != 'D'){
  $i++;
}

echo $i;
// 0

?>
```

Keep in mind that the regex `/\s+/` will only replace white-space characters. So it may be possible that your 'D', while it does look like 'D', actually contains other content. We don't know what your goal is for this code, but it looks like you should improve to regular expression based on the input.